# PHP While Loop Errors

Tags: php, arrays, loops, if-statement, while-loop

Can anyone help me find the errors in this piece of code. When I try running it it says there is an unexpected ';' on line 10 but I'm not sure where this would be. Thanks
 `

```
$lines = array (
    0=>'Once upon a time',
    1=>'There lived a small green frog that lived',
    2=>'on a lilypad in a pond. ',
    3=>'One day a princess came along and kissed it.'
);

$max = count($lines) ;
$out = null ;
while ($i = 0; $i<$max;  $i++) {
    $opentag = '' ;
    $closetag = '' ;

    if ($i = 0) {
        $opentag = '<h1>' ;
        $closetag = '</h1>' ;
    }
    if ($i = 1 )     {
        $opentag = '<p>' ;
    }
    if ($i = ($max-1) )     {
        $closetag = '</p>' ;
    }

    $out = $opentag . $lines[$i] $closetag  ;

}
echo $out ;

?>`
```

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple errors in the above code:

Firstly, you are using `for` conditions in a `while` loop, so you need to use:

```
for ($i = 0; $i<$max;  $i++) {
}
```

And nextly, on this line:

```
$out = $opentag . $lines[$i] $closetag  ;
```

You are missing a `.` between `$lines[$i]` and `$closetag`

You are also using incorrect operators in your `if` statements.

`==` Compare statements, return true if equal, return false if not equal.

`=` Set left side to equal right side

```
if($i = 1){}
```

The above will return true while setting `$i` to the value of 1.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that there are too many errors / mistakes in your code.

Firstly make it `For` loop instead `while`.

Than you missing `.` in below line,

```
$out = $opentag . $lines[$i] . $closetag;
                             ^
```

Also you are doing wrong in your all conditions for it should be like,

```
if ($i == 0) {
```

It should be `==` & not just `=`.

Comment: OP, make sure you correct all of the if statements to include double equal signs, not just the one mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

this is wrong :

```
while ($i = 0; $i<$max;  $i++) {
```

Please check the while syntax. I think you need to use `for` there.

```
for($i = 0; $i<$max;  $i++) {
```